# Is it possible to create subtypes in typescript?

Tags: typescript, types

Sorry if this this has been answered elsewhere, I wasn't exactly sure the best way to query for the question.

Is it possible to create types in TypeScript that index or something to a different type? For example:

```
const addUserAction: Actions.User.Add = ....
const removeUserAction: Actions.User.Remove = ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use indexed access to your types. For example:

```
interface Actions {
    User: {
        Add: () => void;
        Remove: () => void;
    }
}

const addUserAction: Actions['User']['Add'] = () => null;
const removeUserAction: Actions['User']['Remove'] = () => null;
```

I think [this link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) should help a little more.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you have a type defined for example:

```
interface Actions {
  User: {
    Add: string
  }
}
```

You can use `Actions['User']` to address the `User` type.